# Centering terms of equation with tag

Tags: equations, arrays, alignment, tag

This minimal example

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{ccc}
        f(x) & =& \displaystyle\int_0^1 f'(x) d x\\[.2cm]
        e^{i\pi} +1 &=& 0\\
        g(x)&=& 2 f(x)\\
        2x+12&=&3
        \end{array}
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

produces the following result

[image]

What if one wants to put the tag next to the second or the third equation, keeping the horizontal alignment at the centre for each column? Is there a way to do it automatically without specifying space for each cell? I need to have exactly this alignment, hence the `align` environment does not fit in this case.

**EDIT:** Since I only got comments on the fact I do not use `align`, I publish another example to explain the reason for the choice.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cccc}
    (2x+1)^p & =&c(p)&(x+1)^{p+1}\\[.2cm]
    \downarrow&& \downarrow&\downarrow\\
   (2x+1)&=&2&(x+1)^2 \\[1ex]
    x^2-1&=&0&
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: this really should be done with align, array is not suitable for setting equations the horizontal spacing is wrong and here all but one cell are set in inline math mode not displaystyle. It will then handle the number placement as you need as well.

Comment: I know the horizontal spacing is wrong, but I need to separate many terms with this space. It is a conscious choice.

Comment: Hope the combination of `\begin{equation}` and `\begin{aligned}` will helps you...

Comment: It has almost the same behaviour of `align`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, if you must, push everything into the array (or rather `tabular*` to force full width)

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
@{}
c
@{\extracolsep{\textwidth minus \textwidth}}
>{$\displaystyle}c<$
!{\extracolsep{0pt}}
>{$\displaystyle}c<$
>{$\displaystyle}c<$
@{\extracolsep{\textwidth minus \textwidth}}
r}
&        f(x) & =& \int_0^1 f'(x) d x\\[.2cm]
&        e^{i\pi} +1 &=& 0 &(\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation)\\
&        g(x)&=& 2 f(x)\\
&        2x+12&=&3
        \end{tabular*}
\]

zzz
\[
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
@{}
c
@{\extracolsep{\textwidth minus \textwidth}}
>{$\displaystyle}c<$
!{\extracolsep{0pt}}
>{$\displaystyle}c<$
>{$\displaystyle}c<$
>{$\displaystyle}c<$
@{\extracolsep{\textwidth minus \textwidth}}
r}
&    (2x+1)^p & =&c(p)&(x+1)^{p+1}&(\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation)\\[.2cm]
&    \downarrow&& \downarrow&\downarrow\\
&   (2x+1)&=&2&(x+1)^2 &(\refstepcounter{equation}\theequation)\\[1ex]
&    x^2-1&=&0&
    \end{tabular*}
\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `align` with the help of `eqparbox`.

The first mandatory argument to `\eqmathbox` should be a unique key for the boxes you want to set to the same width.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand{\eqmathbox}[3][c]{\eqmakebox[#2][#1]{$\displaystyle#3$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align}
  \eqmathbox{L1}{f(x)}        &= \eqmathbox{R1}{\int_0^1 f'(x)\,dx} \notag\\
  \eqmathbox{L1}{e^{i\pi} +1} &= \eqmathbox{R1}{0} \\
  \eqmathbox{L1}{g(x)}        &= \eqmathbox{R1}{2 f(x)}\\
  \eqmathbox{L1}{2x+12}       &= \eqmathbox{R1}{3} \notag
\end{align}

\begin{align}
  \eqmathbox{L2}{(2x+1)^p}   &=                     \eqmathbox{R2-1}{c(p)} \;
                                                    \eqmathbox{R2-2}{(x+1)^{p+1}} \notag\\
  \eqmathbox{L2}{\downarrow} &\mathrel{\phantom{=}} \eqmathbox{R2-1}{\downarrow} \;
                                                    \eqmathbox{R2-2}{\downarrow} \notag\\
  \eqmathbox{L2}{(2x+1)}     &=                     \eqmathbox{R2-1}{2}\;
                                                    \eqmathbox{R2-2}{(x+1)^2} \\
  \eqmathbox{L2}{x^2-1}      &= \eqmathbox{R2-1}{0} \notag
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]